# How to handle apostophee while inserting record in dynamic sal

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

Here is sample stored procedure.Real SP contains 35 parameter.Out of that only one parameter Message can contain apostrophe. If I try to insert such record into table,getting error.How to handle that.

```
 Create Procedure ProcInsertRecord
    @Name varchar(30),
    @mobile_no varchar(30),
    @message varchar(30),
    @Address varchar(30),
    @Designation varchar(30)
    as
    begin

    set @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ['+@table+'](Name,Mobile,Message,Address,Designation) values ('''+@Name +''' , '+@mobile_no+' , '''+@message+''','''+@Address+''','''@Designation+''')

    sp_helptext @SQL 

    end
```

Comment: Replace apostrophe (`'`) with double one (`''`). Of course better soulution would be to use `sp_executesql` procedure.

Comment: Your current code is a security hazard as it's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  

Also, it indicates a design problem as many tables share the same structure and defer only by table name. With the exception of lookup tables (simple tables that contains id and name of different entities), this is usually a bad design. 

Read my blog post called [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server-%ef%bb%bf/)  for more information on how to safely execute dynamic SQL in SQL Server.

Comment: Where do you get the `@Table` variable from? It's not declared in the code you've posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comments, to the question, there are several problems with your current code - First and foremost, it suggests a database design problem.

With the exception of lookup and system-versioned tables, creating multiple tables with the same structure that only defers by name is usually a sign that you are mixing meta-data with data - meaning that data leaks from your tables content to your tables structure.

The difference in the table names should be eliminated and the tables should be united into a single table, containing (at least) one more column to indicate the difference.

With that being said, There are cases when you simply can't change the database structure - and if these is the case, you will still need a dynamic SQL Solution.

The second problem with your code is that it's vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.
If someone was to use that procedure and set the last parameter value to something like [`'bob'');DROP TABLE Students;--'`](https://xkcd.com/327/) (or some other table name), your code can't stop that attack.

Also, the code you've shown in the question doesn't declare the `@table` variable anywhere, but I just assume you've missed that when writing the question.

The one problem you do complain about (which is the inability to use a string that contains an apostrophe (`'`) as a variable) will be resolved once you changed your procedure to a safe execution using `sp_execute_sql`.

There is only one rule to create a injection-safe dynamic SQL, and it is actually very simple - **Parameterize what you can, White-list what you can't.**

So, if I had to create a dynamic SQL stored procedure for this insert - this is how I would do it (Please also note the comments in the code):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcInsertRecord
    @Name varchar(30),
    @mobile_no varchar(30),
    @message varchar(30),
    @Address varchar(30),
    @Designation varchar(30),
    @table sysname
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- declare your variables. Don't use nvarchar(max) unless you have to. 
        DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000), 
                @LineBreak nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10), 
                @ParamDefinition nvarchar(4000);

        -- White list your table name: making sure not only that it exists,
        -- but also it has all the columns you are using in your insert statement.
        IF EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM InformationSchema.Columns
            WHERE Column_Name IN('Name', 'Mobile', 'Message', 'Address', 'Designation')
            AND Table_Name = @table
            GROUP BY Table_Name
            -- This is usually count(distinct xxx), but column names are unique in a table.
            HAVING COUNT(Column_Name) = 5 
        )

        BEGIN
            -- QUOTENAME protects your query from breaking on table names with spaces or other "strage" chars in their name.
            -- Use line breaks to make your query readable.
            SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@table) +' (Name, Mobile, Message, Address, Designation) '+ @LineBreak + 
                       N'VALUES (@Name, @mobile_no, @message, @Address, @Designation)'

            -- When dealing with dynamic SQL, print is your best friend.
            PRINT @SQL 

            SET @ParamDefinition = 
                N'@Name varchar(30),
                  @mobile_no varchar(30),
                  @message varchar(30),
                  @Address varchar(30),
                  @Designation varchar(30)'

            -- Unremark only when print displays a valid SQL.
            --EXEC sp_ExecuteSql 
            --     @SQL, 
            --     @ParamDefinition, 
            --     @Name, @mobile_no, @message, @Address, @Designation

        END
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You've lost some characters.

Try:

```
DECLARE
    @Name VARCHAR(30) = 'Name',
    @mobile_no VARCHAR(30) = 'Mobile',
    @message VARCHAR(30) = 'Message',
    @Address VARCHAR(30) = 'Adress',
    @Designation VARCHAR(30) = 'Designation',
    @SQL VARCHAR(1000) = 'SQL',
    @table VARCHAR(100) = 'table'


SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [' + @table + '](Name,Mobile,Message,Address,Designation) values (''' + @Name + ''' , ' + @mobile_no + ' , ''' + @message + ''',''' + @Address + ''',''' + @Designation + ''')'

PRINT @SQL
```

Comment: Not only does this not answer the OP's question, it perpetuates the security hazard of the original code.

Comment: I want to handle apostophee.I am not able to see apostophee in message here.